# Pentaho reportviewer URL not loading in iframe

Tags: html, pentaho

Am new to pentaho.

I try to display the report using pentaho reportviewer in iframe i use **.prpt** file to load the report.

I used the following url in iframe

```
http://172.20.10.30:8080/pentaho/content/reporting/reportviewer/report.html?solution=steel-wheels&path=%2Freports&name=Inventory.prpt&userid=joe&password=password
```

If i invoke the above URL in the browser it display the report. I don't know the problem in the above code.

Hear is my Iframe code

```
<html>
        <head>
            <title>Sensatron Issue Testing</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p><strong></strong><b> Sensatron Issue Testing.</b></p>
            <iframe width="1300px" height="750px" src="http://172.20.10.30:8080/pentaho/content/reporting/reportviewer/report.html?solution=steel-wheels&path=%2Freports&name=Inventory.prpt&userid=joe&password=password" name="Bharat" >
            </iframe><br>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result:
    iframe empty

Pentaho Server and its version.

I use pentaho BIserver4.5 to generate report using .prpt file

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This old question hasn't been answered yet and I also tried to find a solution.

One of solution is show html version of report as suggested in
http://pentahoreportingandintegration.blogspot.com/2013/04/pentaho-report-integration-in-iframe.html

But I believe the better solution is mine. I explained in my blog:
http://fabiantowang.blogspot.com/2013/07/embed-pentaho-report-viewer-to-web.html