# Pentaho BI - Anonymous access

Tags: pentaho

I am trying to enable Anonymous access to my local Pentaho BI v5.4 server. I want to bypass the login page. I followed all the instructions mentioned here: http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fsecurity_guide%2Ftask_removing_security.html

Now the login page is not displayed but all pages appear blank with 500 server errors when checked in the Chrome console.

[image: Pentaho Anonymous Access Errors]

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: See my Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28404241/pentaho-bi-server-report-without-log-in/28414637#28414637

Comment: Thanks for the reply Marlon. I have made some progress with your help. The content now shows up. I lost at the point where it says to add multiple lines to \pentaho\server\biserver-ee\pentaho-solutions\system\applicationContext-spring-security.xml file. This being an XML file I cannot add those lines just anywhere in that file. Can you exactly specify where to add those lines. As per the official documentation I have already added CDATA thing under FilterSecurityInterceptor`<![CDATA[ CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON
\A/.*\Z=Anonymous,Authenticated ]]>`

Comment: Add it just under `CONVERT_URL_TO_LOWERCASE_BEFORE_COMPARISON` in that file.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Sorry, I am unable to upvote, SO shows an error that I have undone my upvote and it does not allow me to redo. I guess I need some training on using SO as well ;)