# Viewing pentaho dashboard outside pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I have created a dashboard in pentaho User console. I want to view it outside the User console.(Without logging in to user console) Is it possible ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13758578/pentaho-reportviewer-url-not-loading-in-iframe

Answer (score 3):

```
    Yes. It is possible. 
    You need get two things.
    1)Get URL for the dashboard
    2)Allow URL authentication.
```

### 1)Dashboard URL

```
---------------
    The dashboard url structure will be like this.
```

> http://localhost:8080/pentaho/plugin/pentaho-cdf-dd/api/renderer/render?solution=***RootDirectoryName***&path=***SubDirectoryName***&file=***your_dashboard.wcdf***&userid=admin&password=password

```
    if you have directory structure like this in your pentaho

 -

       Home
       ---->Admin
       ---->Suzy
       ---->tiffiny 
       Public
       ----->myDashBoard
       ----------->myDashboard.wcdf
       ----->SampleDashBoard
       ----->.....
       ----->.....etc

Public and Home are root directories, and Suzy,SampleDashBoard are sub Directories.
Example if you want to use myDashboard.wcdf dashboard then you use this link.
```

> http://localhost:8080/pentaho/plugin/pentaho-cdf-dd/api/renderer/render?solution=home&path=suzy&file=iq_dashboard.wcdf&userid=admin&password=password

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

### 2)Allowing URL Authentication

```
go to your pentaho directory ex:- **
```

> D:\yourDirectory\pentaho-server-ce-7.0.0.0-25\pentaho-server\pentaho-solutions\system\

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

**
open security.properties file in editor.
```

> > ### security.properties

```
  change this code from false to true.
```

> requestParameterAuthenticationEnabled=true

```
------------------------------------------

>save file and close it. 
>restart pentaho server. 
>Open your browser and enter the dashboard link as generated in step 1. 
>Now your dashboard will render on browser.
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

If your dashboard was created with the CDE, you can embedded it in your web applications in three ways:

1. Enabling the requireJS flag in settings within the CDE and embedding the same via a rendering plugin.
2. Using iframe and calling the dashboard link passing authentication via URL.
3. Using the components of the CDF and placing in the code of your application.

You can choose the best way according your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no : If you double-click on the tab (here, I mean the tab inside the PUC) of your dashboard, the PUC will ask you if you want to open it in a tab of your browser. Answer yes and then you get your dashboard in a tab. The url ens with something like ' generatedcontent/ts=...' : copy it up toand including 'generatedcontent' : you can now directly see the dashboard BUT an authentification is still required

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you first have:

1. Double click the dashboard to open it in a new tab in the browser, copy the entire url including the ts
2. Activate url authentication on the server  [activing url autentication](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.3/0P0/000/090)
3. Access the link, which you copied in step 1 by adding the following to the end &userid=**YOUR_USER**&password=**YOUR_PASSWORD**

Another way to do this is configuring pentaho with cas [Switch to Central Authentication Service (CAS)](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/5.1/0P0/150/010/060/000)

I hope I help you